# Convert DOCX Bytestream to PDF Bytestream Python

Tags: python, pdf, io, docx, bytestream

I currently have a program that generates a .docx document using the python-docx library.

Upon completing the building of the .docx file I save it into a Bytestream as so

```
file_stream = io.BytesIO()
document.save(file_stream)
file_stream.seek(0)
```

Now, I need to convert this word document into a PDF. I have looked at a few different libraries for conversion such as docx2pdf or even doing it manually using comtypes as so

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = "Input_file_path.docx"
out_file = "output_file_path.pdf"

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

The problem is, I need to do this conversion in memory and cannot physically save the DOCX or the PDF to the machine. Every converter I've seen requires a filepath to the physical document on the machine and I do not have that.

Is there a way I can convert the DOCX filestream into a PDF stream just in memory?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found an answer for this? i have a similar requirement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method is a little convoluted, but it works entirely in memory, and you get the option to add custom CSS to style the final document.
Convert the DOCX bytestream to HTML using [mammoth](https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth), and the resulting HTML to PDF using [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/).

Here's an example

```py
# create a dummy docx file
from docx import Document
document = Document()
document.add_paragraph('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.')

# create a bytestream
import io
file_stream = io.BytesIO()
document.save(file_stream)
file_stream.seek(0)

# convert the docx to html
import mammoth
result = mammoth.convert_to_html(file_stream)

# >>> result.value
# >>> '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>'

# convert html to pdf
import pdfkit
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(result.value)
```

If you want to output the stream to a file, just do

```py
with open('test.pdf','wb') as file:
    file.write(pdf)
```

Comment: Does this even show images

Answer (score -3):

i think you want to convert docx file to pdf file , then follow these steps:

Install the package:

```
pip install docx2pdf
```

Code:

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert("input.docx")
convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
convert("my_docx_folder/")
```

Thanks and if I am mistaken please tell me to correct it

Comment: The question was if the conversion could be done *in memory*. This is still with files. OP knows how to convert already, just not without involving files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Revisto. Yes I saw that with docx2pdf, but I need to do it fully in memory